# Python Selenium Find Element by Name - throwing up an error

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, find, element

```
username_textbox = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"email")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)
```

When i try to do a find element by name and name = 'email' i get an error. I suspect it may be related to required_field = 'email' - is there a way to do find element by required field?

[image]

Comment: What is the full traceback of the error?

Comment: i noticed after inputting email into the field that the value > == is the one that should be filled out. Is there a way to input username into value >==

Answer (score 0):

Try to find element by xpath.
[How to get element xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzJyj.png)

Use:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("element xpath")